# Kinect not recognized by OpenNI drivers

Tags: kinect, openni, openni-launch, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Our lab recently got a PrimeSense Carmine sensor, which isn't supported by ROS Fuerte's OpenNI drivers. We followed the suggestions of a previous ROS answers post, which added support for the Carmine but appears to have broken support for the Kinect. When we run openni.launch using the Kinect, we get the following error:

```
[ INFO] [1361682271.503512749]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

The Kinect, however, is clearly visible to the operation system (Ubuntu 12.04):

```
Bus 002 Device 015: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Bus 002 Device 017: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
```

Has anyone gotten all of these sensors to work simultaneously under ROS Fuerte or ROS Groovy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56109/kinect-not-recognized-by-openni-drivers/) by [Calder](https://answers.ros.org/users/4279/calder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2013-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the avin2 drivers as per this solution here:

[http://answers.ros.org/question/60562/ubuntu-12042-and-openni_launch-not-detecting-kinect-after-update/]

---

Originally posted by [djtubig-malicex](https://answers.ros.org/users/4667/djtubig-malicex/) with karma: 176 on 2013-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0